# Using the python unicode function

Tags: python, unicode

I'm working on a [project](http://ven-diagram.herokuapp.com/) that compares text.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
def post(self):
    A = unicode(flask.request.form['A'])
    B = unicode(flask.request.form['B'])
```

I posted large pieces of text from project gutenberg and I get errors like this:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Based on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) I have tried errors ignore and errors replace and get the error:

TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

If possible I want to be able to take in the most robust set of characters possible. I was hoping there was a python library that would allow this.

Here is more of the code. I think the problem may occur when I try to turn my input into a string.

```
    C = A.split()
    D = B.split()
    Both = []
    for x in C:
        if x in D:
            Both.append(x)
    for x in range(len(Both)):
        Both[x]=str(Both[x])
    Final = []
    for x in set(Both):
        Final.append(x)
    MissingA = []
    for x in C:
        if x not in Final and x not in MissingA:
            MissingA.append(x)
    for x in range(len(MissingA)):
        MissingA[x]=str(MissingA[x])
    MissingB = []
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data is not already Unicode?

Comment: I didn't know I couldnt go from unicode to unicode. It could be any kind of data pasted into a web form.

Comment: But Flask almost certainly converts the input, so that what you receive in `request.form` is Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is more of the code. I think the problem may occur when I try to
>   turn my input into a string.

I think that's right - try eliminating the `str()` calls.